# Is there a known method to dissect Jessen's icosahedron and rearrange to form a cube?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry, dissection

It can be shown that [Jessen's icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessen%27s_icosahedron) is scissors-congruent to a cube, meaning that it can be sliced into smaller polyhedral pieces that can be rearranged to form a solid cube. What is the simplest way to perform this dissection and reassembly? What cuts are required and how many pieces are necessary?

Comment: Excellent question! Given that the final cube's side length is $2^{-4/3}5^{1/3}$ times the long edge length and $2^{1/6}3^{-1/2}5^{1/3}$ times the short edge length, I would be a little surprised if anything super nice were possible; e.g., I don't think all cuts can be parametrized by rational coordinates. But maybe there's something funkier that can still be done in a "nice" way?

Comment: Since it is flexible I wonder if you could define a "rigid" version for your question.

Comment: @Moti: The polyhedron is not actually flexible, it is just susceptible to changes in its shape which cause nonzero but very small changes in its edge lengths, making it appear flexible in all but the most precise physical models. See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessen%27s_icosahedron#Structural_rigidity) for more.

Comment: The trouble is with this "small changes" that makes it different dissections with different "small changes". I was making dissections even in 3D - what is the exact shape that you want to make into a cube?

Comment: For the edge length of the cube, I get $\sqrt[3]{\frac {9 + 5\sqrt{5}}{12}}$ times the short edge length of the Jessen icosahedron. I offer that here only because it conflicts with the value given in an earlier comment. I have doubts whether that is constructible, but that would not preclude the dissection.

Comment: @Pope: I'm using http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/Jessen.html, which lists a volume of $20$ relative to a short edge length of $\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect: Honestly, I do not believe I had seen this figure before yesterday, but it is not so complicated. It begins with a regular icosahedron. Gouges are cut through six pairs of adjacent faces, leaving the vertices unchanged. The short edges are also edges of the original solid, and the circumradius is unchanged. The circumradius should be $\frac{\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$ times the short edge length, just as it is with the regular icosahedron. That is one more disagreement I have with the linked page. Its reference link is a dead-end. Nice image though.

Comment: @Pope: Jessen's icosahedron does *not* begin with a regular icosahedron; the shape you describe is a different object which does not have right angles between faces. See the Wikipedia article linked in the OP for coordinates of Jessen's icosahedron.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect: I see now. I was using this description from a [Wolfram article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JessensOrthogonalIcosahedron.html). It cannot be right, as it does not result in any right dihedral angles.

Comment: @Pope: Huh, strange that they got it wrong! I started following their references - they cite *The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Geometry*, whose incorrect description of the polyhedron on p. 161 cites in turn [*Unstable Polyhedral Structures*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689996) by Michael Goldberg (1978), whose incorrect description of the polyhedron cites Jessen's original article [*Orthogonal Icosahedra*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24524998), which *does* give the correct coordinates in section $7$. So the Mathworld error stems from a misconception of Goldberg, I think.